# Водители погрузчика/погрузчиков

Tags: грамматика, словосочетания, единственное-множественное-число

*Провести внеплановое обучение водителей погрузчика по данному отклонению.*

Какое окончание правильное: водителей погрузчик**а** или водителей погрузчик**ов**?

Comment: погрузчиков, но в целом кривоватое предложение, не ясно что такое "по данному отклонению". "Водители погрузчиков работают в портах, на железной дороге, в аэропортах, на предприятиях промышленности...Если у вас уже имеются базовые навыки и желание получить новую специальность, то переподготовка на водителя погрузчика – именно то, что нужно.  Об этом сообщает..." https://auto.rambler.ru/roadaccidents/50676848-voditel-pogruzchika-chto-za-professiya-i-kak-prohodit-obuchenie/

Comment: Может быть: необходимо провести внеплановую переподготовку водителей всех погрузчиков *по данному отклонению*?

Answer (score 1):

• Первая ситуация
Погрузчик только один. На нём в несколько смен работают водители.
Тогда правильно так: *обучение водителей **погрузчика***.

• Вторая ситуация
Погрузчиков много и водителей много (что чаще всего).
Тогда правильно так: *обучение водителей **погрузчиков***.

• В МАС: **отклонение** — отступление от чего-либо, несовпадение с чем-либо, разница по сравнению с чем-либо. *Отклонение от нормы.*
Речь, скорее всего, идет о какой-то внештатной ситуации.

Тогда предложение, думаю, лучше перестроить:
*Провести внеплановое обучение водителей погрузчиков в связи с данным отклонением.*

Answer (score 1):

Хороший вопрос, интересно посмотреть на статистику. Если мы делаем акцент на статусе людей - водитель погрузчика, тогда наверное можно не согласовывать в числе. Если мы делаем акцент на множестве погрузчиков, то нужно согласовывать.

```
У нас в стране водители погрузчика получают больше, чем работники склада.
```

В вашем случае речь идет скорее о конкретных погрузчиках (погрузчиках предприятия), поэтому единственное число немного не звучит. Хотя я обычно не согласовываю числа в подобных словосочетаниях:

```
Выпишите окончание слов "дома","дворы","комья". // можно воткнуть предлог у
Найдите максимум функций f(x)=-x^2, f(x)=sin(x) // можно воткнуть предлог для
Дайте определение плохих людей // можно воткнуть слово "класса"
Спортсмены других стран не участвуют в соревновании. // здесь страны не звучит
Спортсмены другой страны будут удалены с соревнований. // здесь нормально, можно воткнуть слово "любой"
Люди западной страны не способны к переезду на восток. // акцент на статусе
Люди западных стран объединяйтесь. // акцент на странах
```

Comment: Ничего не понял, но плюсану за уверенность.

Comment: Ну тут вопрос что звучит, что не звучит, что употребляется, что нет, а потом подвести теорбазу под это. Ведь это огромный класс словосочетаний с разными свойствами